# Convert Array of Unstructured Objects to CSV Format - JS

Tags: javascript, csv

I want to convert the following array of objects to a CSV with the format:

Array:

```
            const arr = [ 
                {
                    "Test": 1,
                    "Test2": 3,
                    "Test3": 2
                },
                {
                    "Test": 5,
                    "Test2": 1,
                    "Test3": 3
                },
                {
                    "Test": 4,
                    "Test4": "",
                    "Test2": 5,
                    "Test3": 1
                },
                {
                    "Test": 4,
                    "Test2": 5,
                    "Test3": 1,
                    "Test5": 1
                },
                {
                    "Test": 4,
                    "Test2": 5,
                    "Test3": 1,
                    "Test5": 6
                }
            ];
```

Expected Output

```
Test,Test2,Test3,Test4,Test5
1, 3, 2,,,
5, 1, 3,,,
.
.
.
4,5,1,,6
```

Any recommendations that satisfy a time complexity less than O(n^2)?

Currently, I have nested for-loops to grab all unique keys and their corresponding values then for loops again to try and create a proper output.